# Django forms, integer field is converted to string when accessed from template tags

Tags: django, forms

In Django forms, If we submit an invalid form, The integer field is converted to string field when accessed from template tags.

(i.e): `Status = forms.IntegerField( max_value=20, required=True)`

Accessed on page using template tags

```
{% if  form.Status.value == 1 %}
do something...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please format the code so it's readable, so that it's easy for people to help you.

Comment: The answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318236