# Django form - type of variable changes when reloaded after validation error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have spent some time on this but cannot figure out the exact cause of the following behaviour.

I have a Django form and in the template I am trying to see if an integer is present in a list and then doing something with it.

```
{% if pk in form.area.value %} {# form.area.value is a list like [7,21] #}
    do something
{% endif%}
```

Everything works fine except in cases where the form is reloaded after a validation error. In such cases, the list that I am comparing with, gets converted to list of strings (from a list of ints) on its own and the `if` test fails. So `[7,21]` above becomes `['7','21']`

In case it helps, this is how the form is being rendered in the view:

On the GET request (where the if condition works fine):

```
form = SchoolForm(instance = school)
return render(request, 'edit-school.html', {'form': form, 'school_id': school_id})
```

After the POST request (where the if condition fails in the template):

```
form = SchoolForm(request.POST or None, instance=school, request=request)
return render(request, 'edit-school.html', {'form': form, 'school_id': school_id})
```

**Update**: Got it to work by converting string values after the POST request in the form back to int by declaring another method in the form (as suggested by @bruno in the answer below) and using it in the template. Here's the code snippet (of how its being used in the template):

```
<div class="checkbox">
    {% for pk, choice in form.area.field.widget.choices %}
        <label for="id_{{sub_type}}_{{form.area.name}}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
            <input class="form-control" id="id_{{sub_type}}_{{form.area.name}}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" name="{{form.area.name}}" type="checkbox" value="{{ pk }}" {% if pk in form.area_values %} checked="checked" {% endif %}/>
            <span class="badge">{{ choice }}</span>
        </label>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104713) without an upvoted or accepted answer. I have tried to explain the above in more detail though.

Comment: This is normal behavior. The question is why you need to inspect a form field's value. You should base decisions on template variables instead. They are guaranteed to be type stable.

Comment: @Melvyn - thanks. `form.area` is a `MultipleChoiceField`. Based on whether a value is checked or not checked, I do something fancy in the template. I am not using the default `CheckboxSelectMultiple` and rendering the checkboxes on my own. Doesn't seem straightforward at the moment how to use template variables instead, but will try to figure it out.

Comment: And that gets filled by the school model, correct? So the model instance of school determines what the value of area is. So instead of providing `school_id` provide the model: `{ 'school': school, ... }`. Then you simply use `school.area` to do the fancy stuff. This seems a bit daunting, so if you provide the relevant bits of SchoolForm and the School model, I will post an answer to connect all the dots.

Comment: @Melvyn No it hasn't been saved in the model yet. This page comes up when there is a validation error. So the values are coming from what the user filled in the form before they hit submit (and the page is now re-rendered with the form data and the validation error message)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to provide more valuable feedback on submission errors. Without providing more code of the template and form, this is hard to answer ("something fancy" translates to code very poorly :) ). FWIW, you can iterate `area.choices`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the user submitted the form, `{{ form.area.value }}` (which in Python resolves to `form["area"].value`) is populated with the raw data from `request.POST`, which are indeed strings.

You didn't clearly explain what kind of "fancy thing" you're trying to do in the template so it's hard to come with a "best" solution for your use case, but as a general rule, templates are not the place for anything fancy - that's what Python is for (either in your view, in your form, in a custom templatetag or filter etc).

A very quick and simple solution would be to add a method to your form that returns the `area` boundfield values as ints:

```
class SchoolForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # your code here

    def area_values(self):
        # XXX this might require some conditionals or
        # error handling to be failsafe 
        # works with both python 2.x and 3.x
        return [int(v) for v in self["area"].value()]
```

then in your template, replace `{% if pk in form.area.value %}` with `{% if pk in form.area_values %}`

Comment: Good answer, but area_values can best return `[choice for choice, label in self.choices]`. That remains type stable should he decide to change them to some other type.

Comment: As I understand it, what the OP wants are the selected values (either as initial values from the instance or from the request.POST after submission), not the whole set of available choices which your code would return.

Comment: Ack, you're right. Looking at [`ChoiceField.valid_value`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/forms/fields.py#L826) it compares text representations of the choice. But it also accounts for optgroups. Maybe the best here is to follow that logic and instead of return a bool, return `k` from the outer loop. Then create the list like that. (as a more general solution)

Comment: Well until we really now what the OP is trying to do there's no "best" solution...

Comment: - @brunodesthuilliers Thanks. Still need to check but I think this will work for me. The fancy stuff is badges. I am rendering badges manually instead of checkboxes (for example, see the 'Sector' section [here](goo.gl/ubVEch) ). I am iterating through all the choices, those that are checked get badges filled with colour, others dont get coloured badges/are transparent. Perhaps I'll come back and post a simplified version of the code so that it becomes clearer.

Comment: @Anupam for the record we solved similar needs by creating our own select / multiple select widgets, so all the complexity is handled in the widget code itself and the template remains clean and simple (I wish I could say so from the widgets code but that's another issue...)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Perhaps I should have created a widget for this one. Will consider moving the code to it.

Comment: Note that the widgets rendering system - and specially most of the select/multiselect widgets implementation - has changed in django 1.11 (in a way that should make customisation easier AFAICT), so if you're still using 1.10 or older you may want to wait until you upgrade to 1.11+ before doing so.

Comment: wow that is quite important to know. I am on 1.10! Did not prioritize upgrading since we went live and I wasn't sure of any breaking changes/other bottlenecks.

Comment: @Anupam related change infos here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#template-based-widget-rendering and here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#template-widget-incompatibilities-1-11

Comment: **Update**: This solution works for me. I have proposed 2 edits to the answer (corrected syntax for the value method and returning a list instead of a map). Also updated the question with the exact thing that I was trying to do.

Comment: edit: used a list comp instead of `map` to be directly compatible with python 2.x and 3.x